# Do we need the Undo tag

Tags: discussion

The [undo](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/undo) looks useless and I think it needs removing.

Currently it is only used on [one question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/29045/why-is-there-no-redo-function-in-blender) (which is a duplicate of [another question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26861/step-forward-button-in-blender-redo) which didn't use the tag and got answers).

I can't see [undo](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/undo) being used anywhere else.

Comment: Good catch, as iklsr said, (almost) anyone can create a new tag, and some of them, like this one, are not needed at all. PS this is a perfect use of the meta, any time you have a question, or concern about the main site post a question here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was just created, new users create these all the time however we don't normally have tags for simple features like this, it has been removed.